# MiNiFi GetFile processor fails to get large files

Tags: file, bigdata, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'm running apache **MiNiFi c++**, The flow starts with a `GetFile` processor.

The input directory includes some large files, and when I run MiNiFi the files above ~1.5 GB fail and do not get queued.

The log file states:

> [org::apache::nifi::minifi::processors::GetFile] [Warning] failed to stat *large_file_path_here*

The other smaller files are queued as expected.

Does anyone have a clue what can be wrong? Why can't the processor manage the larger files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a max queue data size set for the connection?

Comment: Also, can you please share your agent version and what OS your MiNiFi is running on?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi I don't think I have a max queue data size. Back Pressure is set to 10000 and Size Threshold is set to 3GB.

Comment: using minifi cpp 0.7.0, running on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you found seems like a bug that is present even in the current MiNiFi implementation even up to today. The issue is that file sizes you mentioned, a narrowing exception happens [here](https://github.com/apache/nifi-minifi-cpp/blob/minifi-cpp-0.9.0-RC2/libminifi/src/core/ContentSession.cpp#L75) when trying to determine the length of the file to be written into the content repository.

We will try to fix this issue asap.

Comment: Why then am I getting the exception "failed to stat" and not the exception written in line 78 in the link you've sent?

Comment: It seems like, the root cause of this issue is that we use _stat on windows, but we should be using _stat64  to query files larger than 2GB. This is a minor issue compared to what I described. MiNiFi should have been tested with large files: I will make sure to increase the coverage for the upcoming releases.